# Convert a string into list of list

Tags: python, string, list

I have a string, say:

`s = "abcdefghi"`

I need to create a list of lists of this such that the list formed will :-

`list = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f'],['g','h','i']]`

Now the string can be anything but will always have length n * n

So if `n = 4.`

The `len(s) = 16`

And the list will be:

```
[['1','2','3','4'],['5','6','7','8'],...,['13','14','15','16']]
```

So each list in the list of lists will have length 4.

So I want to write a function which takes string and n as input and gives 
a list of list as output where the length of each list within the list is n.

How can one do this ?

UPDATE :

How can you convert the above list of list back to a string ?

So if l = `list = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f'],['g','h','i']]`

How to convert it to a string :-

`s = "abcdefghi"`

I found a solution for this in stackoverflow :-

```
s = "".join("".join(map(str,l)) for l in list)
```

Thanks everyone !

Comment: What did you try so far? And what's the issue in it?

Comment: This is [itertools grouper recipe](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a list comprehension that does the job:

```
[list(s[i:i+n]) for i in range(0, len(s), n)]
```

If `n * n == len(s)` is always true, then just put

```
n = int(len(s) ** 0.5) # Or use math.sqrt
```

For the edit part here's another list comprehension:

```
''.join(e for e in sub for sub in l)
```

Comment: or `[list(s[n*i:(i+1)*n]) for i in range(len(s) // n)]`

Comment: That was quick !! Thanks a ton !

Comment: Yeah it was 9, my bad I thought n was string length... Removing my comment

Comment: And how can you convert the list of list back to the original string ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a personal fan of numpy...

```
import numpy as np
s = "abcdefghi"
n = int(np.sqrt(len(s)))
a = np.array([x for x in s], dtype=str).reshape([n,n])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from math import sqrt
def listify(s):
    n = sqrt(len(s))
    g = iter(s)
    return [[next(g) for i in range(n)] for j in range(n)]
```

I like using generators for problems like this